# unable to read data from a CSV file using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, csv, d3.js

I am trying to read data from a csv file using javacsript and no matter what changes I make, the html file shows up as blank. Can some one please guide me as to what I'm doing wrong. I took the basic code from searching around over the internet but even that won't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated and make my life much easier :)..Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var dataset = []
d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {
   dataset = data.map(function(d) { return [ +d["max_i"], +d["min_i"] ]; });
   console.log(dataset)
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

The csv file is as follows:

```
max_i,min_i,max_f,min_f
-122.1430195,-122.1430195,-122.415278,37.778643
-122.1430195,-122.1430195,-122.40815,37.785034
-122.4194155,-122.4194155,-122.4330827,37.7851673
-122.4194155,-122.4194155,-122.4330827,37.7851673
-118.4911912,-118.4911912,-118.3672828,33.9164666
-121.8374777,-121.8374777,-121.8498415,39.7241178
-115.172816,-115.172816,-115.078011,36.1586877
-82.5618186,-82.5618186,-79.2274115,37.9308282
-79.9958864,-79.9958864,-80.260396,40.1787544
-74.1243063,-74.1243063,-74.040948,40.729688
-106.609991,-106.609991,-106.015897,35.640949
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? Are you using Chrome (if so, try another browser, too)?

Comment: No error message at all, just a blank page. Tried it on IE and Mozilla

Comment: Did you look in the [Firefox web console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console)? It looks like all the output from your script will be to the console (so the page should in fact be blank).

Comment: Oh I didn't know about that, I'll check it out right now and let you know

Comment: FYI It outputs the data from console.log in the chrome console, must be the datamap function not working? Sorry I'm not familiar with d3

Comment: I'll say again I'm not familiar with d3 so I'm not sure what the data map function does, but so long as it's not manipulating the dom nothing is going to happen in the html so you won't see anything

Comment: I don't see any code that would update the html. All you're doing is reading the CSV into memory.

Comment: Oh...I'm totally new to javascript, I was just trying to run the sample codes on the internet first and then try understanding the logic...Where should i make a change in the code? Thank you all for the help, appreciate it :)

Comment: @ mdml I get the following errors using the Firefox web console:

Comment: -TypeError: mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create d3.v3.min.js:3
-The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. datapull.html
-ReferenceError: Console is not defined

Comment: @Khan: relax, those aren't errors, they are warnings and you can worry about them later...

Comment: @dandavis...Thanks...Can you please let me know where to make a change in the code to make it work?

Comment: I usually use jquery to manipulate the dom, import jquery, and you can use a method like html to output the object your setting  http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2

Comment: Thank you so much @haakym .. I have to work with D3 eventually, but I'll try to get some idea from jquery as well. I feel i'm missing out on something very basic here, so pardon my basic questions :)

Comment: You're welcome @Khan, I would have been happy to give a better answer but there's been a power cut just now and running off my phone! Hope the answer I posted can give you some direction.

Comment: If you're running this code locally you will need a webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Outputting the data into a table:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<!-- JQuery import -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<div id="container"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var dataset = [];
d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {
   dataset = data.map(function(d) { return [ +d["max_i"], +d["min_i"] ]; });

   // build a string using html table
   var tableString = "<table border=1>\
                        <thead>\
                            <tr> <td> max_i </td> <td> min_i </td> </tr>\
                        </thead>\
                        <tbody>";
   for (var i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
        tableString += "<tr>";
        tableString += "<td>" + dataset[i][0] + "</td><td>" + dataset[i][1];
        tableString += "</tr>";
   };
   tableString += "</tbody></table>";

   $('#container').html(tableString);
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @haakym..Thanks a lot:)....I eventually want to store data from a csv file into an html table, but that seems a long way off since I cant show the data from a csv file at the moment:/... I tried the code you sent above but it still gives a blank ouput, lets say I ignore the d3 part for now, how would you just display the data read from csv file in jquery?

Comment: No worries, happy to help. HTML table should be a piece of cake, I'll update my answer now, I think I know why it didn't work, because I linked to a local copy of jquery.

Comment: Updated the answer, hope that helps. If you run into errors use the javascript debugger in chrome (f12) or firebug is good for firefox.

Comment: Still blank :/...Can you please tell me what you mean by "local copy of jquery" ?... I'm probably asking very basic questions, but I'm confused with all the api's used in javascript:/

Comment: As @Lars Kotthoff said earlier, If you're running this code locally you will need a webserver - I think this is your issue. Local copy = copy on my C: drive. I am using Wamp server to run the script.

Comment: Oh ok... I am not familiar with the whole webserver concept... Is it needed because I am including:                            "http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" ?                                    I tried a few other source codes which had some D3 visualizations, and they seem to work . Do i still need to install Wamp server or any other software?

Comment: That shouldn't be the issue, I think it's too do with accessing the csv and cross-site policy. I'm a bit confused tbh and can't check right now. It does however work on my PC from wamp. As for using a local server I think you might not need to actually if you access data csv like file:///C:/..yourpath../data.csv then access the web page from the same location. Give it a try and see if it works.

Comment: I tried it like this: "file:///C:/path/data.csv" accessing the page in the same fashion, "file:///C:/path/index.html" in Chrome and it didn't work, it did however work in Firefox. Give it a shot.

Comment: Ok so I entered d3.csv("file:///C:/Users/makif/Desktop/JS prac/datapulling/data.csv", function(data)  and the rest was the same, but it still didnt work for me on firefox or IE...Did it pull data from the csv in your case in firefox?

Comment: Was your html page sitting in the same folder as the csv? Yes it did.

Comment: Yes they are both in the same folder :/

Comment: Can you check what the errors are, run it in chrome, hit f12 then press the console tab. It's most likely still cross site scripting issues, but my firefox settings is allowing - though that is just a guess! You can by pass this I think, looking it up now.

Comment: I get the following errors when i open it in chrome:

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/makif/Desktop/JS%20prac/datapulling/data.csv. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. hakyms.html:1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null hakyms.html:11
Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///C:/Users/makif/Desktop/JS%20prac/datapulling/data.csv'. d3.v3.min.js:1

Comment: Okay this works in chrome for me... firstly recopy the code above and paste in your file then save because I missed a semi colon (worked anyway in firefox but better to be on the safe side). Bring up the windows run window (windows key + r, or go to start->all programs->accessories->run) type the following `chrome --allow-file-access-from-files` then hit ok or press enter, go to your html file in the chrome window that boots up and hopefully you'll see the table!

Comment: You want to make sure the jquery library is being accessed via `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js` unless you downloaded it - not `file:///ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js` as it is in the error you posted above

Comment: Ok so i pasted the code you sent above and get the following errors:XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/makif/Desktop/JS%20prac/datapulling/data.csv. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. d3.v3.min.js:1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null try.html:11
Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///C:/Users/makif/Desktop/JS%20prac/datapulling/data.csv'. d3.v3.min.js:1

Comment: the csv file is not loading for some reason, the jquery library error has gone now though

Comment: Did you try running the webpage from `chrome --allow-file-access-from-files` ??

Comment: oh some progress...so chrome doesnt open up anything, but firefox is now showing a table, however all the values are NaN..I'm guessing changing jquery library path helped here..But not sure why is it displaying NaN for all values

Comment: Yay. Well hopefully you'll get to the solution soon. Do you have any errors in the firebug console? You might save yourself some time if you just install wamp, it's not overly complicated to set up. I can give you my skype or gmail if you need help, writing in the comments is taking it's time.

Comment: gmail would be perfect, you can add me at akifnaveed89@gmail.com... Thank you again for all the help man, really appreciate it :)

Comment: No problem, are you able to use google hangout or chat